# using jquery to reverse animation on second click

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle

I have three boxes with information that I want to open with the specific animation I have already coded. I have coded everything where when one is clicked, the others close, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to have the box close when you click the name the second time, and i don't know why, but the toggle event doesn't work when I try it. Any idea how I could do this? Here is the jquery code:

```
$('.link').click(function(){
        $('#box').animate({
            marginLeft:"0px",
            marginTop:"100px"
            },500).addClass('navigation').animate({
            width:"260px",
            height:"80px"
        },500);
        $('#box2').animate({
            marginLeft:"100px",
            marginTop:"0px",
            width:"60px",
            height:"23px"
            },500).removeClass('navigation');
        $('#box3').animate({
            marginLeft:"200px",
            marginTop:"0px",
            width:"60px",
            height:"23px"
            },500).removeClass('navigation')
    });    
    $('.link2').click(function(){
        $('#box2').animate({
            marginLeft:"0px",
            marginTop:"100px"
            },500).addClass('navigation').animate({
            width:"260px",
            height:"80px"
        },500);
        $('#box').animate({
            marginLeft:"0px",
            marginTop:"0px",
            width:"60px",
            height:"23px"
            },500).removeClass('navigation');
        $('#box3').animate({
            marginLeft:"200px",
            marginTop:"0px",
            width:"60px",
            height:"23px"
            },500).removeClass('navigation');
    });  
    $('.link3').click(function(){
        $('#box3').animate({
            marginLeft:"0px",
            marginTop:"100px"
            },500).addClass('navigation').animate({
            width:"260px",
            height:"80px"
        },500);
        $('#box2').animate({
            marginLeft:"100px",
            marginTop:"0px",
            width:"60px",
            height:"23px"
            },500).removeClass('navigation');
        $('#box').animate({
            marginLeft:"0px",
            marginTop:"0px",
            width:"60px",
            height:"23px"
            },500).removeClass('navigation');    
    });
```

And here is a jsfiddle to make it more clear: http://jsfiddle.net/Unphr/11/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a more generic handler for this process if you do a little renaming in your DOM.

The important addition to the following HTML block is that the `box` class was added to all of the box containers.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="box1" class="box" align="center">
        <div id="link1" class="link"><a> Info </a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="box2" class="box" align="center">
        <div id="link2" class="link"><a> Links </a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="box3" class="box" align="center">
    <div id="link3" class="link"><a> More </a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The following JS is essentially your code refactored to not rely on specifically defined animations for each `box`. In order to do this, it utilizes the jQuery [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to store information in the DOM for latter usage (in this case, the left margin of the box).

**JS**

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    // Get the associated box
    var box = $(this).closest('.box');
    // Get the other boxes
    var otherBoxes = $('.box').not(box);
    // If the box is already active
    if (box.hasClass('active')) {
        // Animate the box out
        animateBoxOut(box);
    } else {
        // Get the original left margin
        var marginLeft = box.css('margin-left');
        // Store the original left margin
        box.data('marginLeft', marginLeft);
        // Animate the box in
        animateBoxIn(box);
        // Animate the other boxes out
        otherBoxes.each(function(index, element) {
            animateBoxOut(element);
        });
    }
});

function animateBoxIn(box) {
    // Animate the box in
    $(box).addClass('active').animate({
        marginLeft:"0px",
        marginTop:"100px"
    },500).animate({
        width:"260px",
        height:"80px"
    });
}

function animateBoxOut(box) {
    // Get the element's stored left margin
    var marginLeft = $(box).data('marginLeft');
    // Animate the box out
    $(box).animate({
        marginLeft:marginLeft,
        marginTop:"0px",
        width:"60px",
        height:"23px"
    },500).removeClass('active');
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ccAkW/3/)**

Comment: You might also like this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Unphr/12/. It saves the original width/height as well and recovers them as needed.

Comment: wow, that one is really cool too! Hey, how would you make the height equivalent of "auto" after the click for the animation so that it will always fit towards the right height? becuase auto doesn't respond well in the animate event